How to bring the equation within the margin
\begin{flalign*}
        Sz(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb Z_n)){}=&\binom{\ell}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{D}\binom{\varphi(d_i)}{2}+\sum_{\substack{i=1}}^D\biggl[ \biggl(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\d_k\nsim d_i}}^D {\varphi(d_k)}+1\biggr)\biggr]\times \ell\times \varphi(d_i)
        \\
        &+\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i<j,d_i\sim d_j}}^D \biggl[ \biggl(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\d_k\sim d_i, d_k\nsim d_j}}^D |K_{\varphi(d_k)}|+1\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\d_k\nsim d_i, d_k\sim d_j}}^D |K_{\varphi(d_k)}|+1\biggr)\biggr] |K_{\varphi(d_i)}| |K_{\varphi(d_j)}|.
        \\
        =&\binom{\ell}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{D}\binom{\varphi(d_i)}{2}+\sum_{\substack{i=1}}^D\biggl[ \biggl(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\d_k\nsim d_i}}^D {\varphi(d_k)}+1\biggr)\biggr]\times \ell\times \varphi(d_i)
        \\
        &+\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i<j,d_i\sim d_j}}^n\biggl[ \biggl(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\d_k\sim d_i, d_k\nsim d_j}}^n {\varphi(d_k)}+1\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\d_k\nsim d_i, d_k\sim d_j}}^n {\varphi(d_k)}+1\biggr)\biggr] {\varphi(d_i)}{\varphi(d_j)}.
        \end{flalign*}

I am having issues with the following code. The second line of the above equation is going beyond the margin of the page. I tried using several tricks but it is still exceeding the margin of the journal.
As per the journal template requirements, I need it within \marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}
Can someone please help me with this? I am clueless how to fix it.

You still need to manually break long lines of display math. There is no way around it.

There's the breqn package. Anyway, I think it's better to break manually long math line.

note you are asking people how to make something fit into a space without saying how big the space is, it is always helpful to provide a complete small document that shows the problem, not just a fragment.

Please advise if you use the amans document class.

You have failed to indicate which document class you use, which font you employ, what the main document font size is, and how wide the textblock is. (Sorry, but the remark about \marginsize is unusable since you haven't provided any information about the paper size.) I've therefore had to make the following assumptions: You employ the article document class, the font you use is Computer Modern, the main document font size is 10pt, and the default textblock width provided by the article document class is in effect.
If these assumptions are valid, your formatting objective may be achieved by (a) introducing an additional line break in some of the \substack expressions and (b) using \smashoperator directives (provided by the mathtools package) to "snug up" the \sum terms either to the right or the left, depending on where there's needless amounts of whitespace.
By the way, what's with the redundant pairs of tall parentheses/brackets in rows 1 and 3?

\documentclass{article}
% for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' and '\smashoperator' macros:
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
% for '\mathbb' and '\nsim' macros:
\usepackage{amssymb} 
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\smopl[1]{\smashoperator[l]{#1}}
\newcommand\smopr[1]{\smashoperator[r]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathit{Sz}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb Z_n)){} % what's with '{}'?
&=\binom{\ell}{2}
 +\sum_{i=1}^{D} \binom{\varphi(d_i)}{2}
 +\sum_{\substack{i=1}}^D 
 \biggl[ \biggl(
 \smopr{\sum_{\substack{k=1,\\d_k\nsim d_i}}^D} 
 \varphi(d_k)+1
 \biggr) \biggr]
 \times \ell \times \varphi(d_i)
\\[\jot]
&\quad+
 \smopl{\sum_{\substack{i,j=1,\\i<j,\\d_i\sim d_j}}^D}
 \biggl[ \biggl(
 \smopr{\sum_{\substack{k=1,\\d_k\sim d_i,\\d_k\nsim d_j}}^D}
 \abs{K_{\varphi(d_k)}}+1
 \biggr) \biggl(
 \smopr{\sum_{\substack{k=1,\\d_k\nsim d_i,\\d_k\sim d_j}}^D} 
 \abs{K_{\varphi(d_k)}}+1
 \biggr) \biggr] 
 \abs{K_{\varphi(d_i)}} \abs{K_{\varphi(d_j)}}
\\[2\jot]
&=\binom{\ell}{2}
 +\sum_{i=1}^{D} \binom{\varphi(d_i)}{2}
 +\sum_{\substack{i=1}}^D
 \biggl[ \biggl(
 \smopr{\sum_{\substack{k=1,\\d_k\nsim d_i}}^D} 
 \varphi(d_k)+1
 \biggr) \biggr]
 \times \ell \times \varphi(d_i)
\\[\jot]
&\quad+
 \smopl{\sum_{\substack{i,j=1,\\i<j,\\d_i\sim d_j}}^n}
 \biggl[ \biggl(
 \smopr{\sum_{\substack{k=1,\\d_k\sim d_i,\\d_k\nsim d_j}}^n}
 \varphi(d_k)+1
 \biggr) \biggl(
 \smopr{\sum_{\substack{k=1,\\d_k\nsim d_i,\\d_k\sim d_j}}^n} 
 \varphi(d_k)+1
 \biggr) \biggr] 
 \varphi(d_i) \varphi(d_j) \,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}

